# The ordering of an std::map

Tags: c++, iterator, stdmap

For an `std::map`, can i always trust `begin()` to return the element with the smallest key according to comparison operators for the type, when iterating?

In other words...

Will `std::map<Key, SomeClass>::iterator smallestKeyIt = someMap.begin();` give me the pair in the map with the smallest key?

Is this the ordering that is quaranteed for an `std::map` or can i configure it somehow? My understanding is that the underlaying tree structure is kept ordered when performing operations such as adding and removing elements.

Comment: `begin` returns an iterator refering to the smallest key. The smallest key is defined by the map's comparison operator, which defaults to `<` but can be overridden. The map remains ordered when inserting or deleteing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can i always trust begin() to return the element with the smallest key according to comparison operators for the type?

Yes.

> Is this the ordering that is quaranteed for an std::map or can i configure it somehow?

Yes. And you can configure the behaviour of comparing by specify the comparator. (The default one is `std::less`.)

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class map;
```

> std::map is a sorted associative container that contains key-value
>   pairs with unique keys. Keys are sorted by using the comparison
>   function Compare. Search, removal, and insertion operations have
>   logarithmic complexity. Maps are usually implemented as [red-black trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

Answer (score 3):

`std::map` is defined as:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class map;
```

You can use your specialized `Compare` to configure how the entries of a `map` are ordered. For example, if you use:

```
std::map<int, double, std::greater<int>> myMap;
```

then, the first entry in `myMap` will have the largest key.